# Monitoring a folder Eclipse

Tags: java, android, photos

I'm making an app that can take photos. If the taken photo is saved into a folder I want a toaster message to appear.

However with my current code when I click the camera button, the toaster just comes up without waiting for the photo to be taken.

Below is the source code to take the photo:

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 0;
public void onClickbtnCamera(View v){
  Intent imageIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
  String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
  Uri uriSavedImage=Uri.fromFile(
    new  File("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera","QR_"+timeStamp+ ".png"));
  imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
  startActivityForResult(imageIntent, 1);
}
```

The toaster I want to show:

```
Toast toast= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
             "Picture was taking", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 100, 0);
toast.show();
```

Can you tell me why my code is failing to do the intended job?

Comment: And what happens? There is no question here.

Comment: @JohnSensebe I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

@Craig The question you've asked isn't clear/complete.

Assuming from the information you have provided, that you want a message to be displayed on a screen once a picture is saved. And you are using

```
imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
```

Have an event listener on imageIntent object. Register that event to the method that contains this piece of code.

```
Toast toast= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Picture was taking", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 100, 0);
        toast.show();
```

PS: This might not be the actual solution but hope should help you to give a direction